# Not able to click on any link in weblogic 12c console

Tags: weblogic

[Weblogic console]
I am not able to click on any link on Weblogic console like deployment, server, data sources etc.
I got error log in putty like below:

tree for URI[/portalConfig/JMS/quota/JMSQuota.book] is invalid

tree for URI[/portalConfig/SNMP/Snmp.book] is invalid

tree for URI[/portalConfig/security/group/SecurityGroup.book] is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Your consoleapp might be corrupted. 
1. Stop your admin server. 
2. Delete tmp, cache folders from `${DOMAIN_HOME}/servers/AdminServer` folder 
3. Start the admin server.

If this doesn't help then you may have to copy the consoleapp folder from working machine to the machine where you seeing this issue. Path for that is:

```
${ORACLE_HOME} wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp
```